# How to change color in horizontal icon bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, icons

I want to be able to change to color of either the green home icon or the green search icon. But whenever I try to change it, it changes it for both of them. I'm not sure if I've explained this well, but any comments or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

```js
console.log('Loaded')
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4CAF50e;
  border: none;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {margin:10}

.icon-bar {
    width: 90px;
 height: 100%;
    background-color: #555;   /*button color*/
}

.icon-bar a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #4289b5;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}























body{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a{
  
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 3;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FC2121;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;  
}

/* Search Style */ 
#search {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
           transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);    
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

#search.open {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
        -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
            transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1); 
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 106;
    display: block;
}

#search input[type="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -51px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   background: transparent;
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   border-left: 0px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    font-size: 40px;
   font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
   padding: 10px;
}
  
#search .close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: 27px;
   color: #fff;
}

#search .close:hover{
  color: #FC2121;
  cursor: pointer;
}








body {margin:0;}

.icon-bartop {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bartop a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bartop a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<body>

<div class="icon-bartop">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <div class="icon-bar">
   <a class="active" href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
 </div>
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it hard to use the snipplet feature in stackoverflow?

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time (and it's just a PITA to have to go to another site to read your question). Just insert your code into a "code snippet", right here in your question.

Comment: The problem is that it say the post is mostly code and won't let me post it as a snippet

Comment: It will if you also include a description of the issue and not just code.

Comment: they are both green because they are both active..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they are both green is because they both have the class active and in the css, the active links have a background color of green. Remove the class = 'active' from the icon that isn't active or which ever one you don't want to be active.

```js
console.log('Loaded')
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4CAF50e;
  border: none;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {margin:10}

.icon-bar {
    width: 90px;
 height: 100%;
    background-color: #555;   /*button color*/
}

.icon-bar a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #4289b5;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}























body{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a{
  
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 3;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FC2121;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;  
}

/* Search Style */ 
#search {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
           transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);    
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

#search.open {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
        -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
            transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1); 
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 106;
    display: block;
}

#search input[type="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -51px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   background: transparent;
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   border-left: 0px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    font-size: 40px;
   font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
   padding: 10px;
}
  
#search .close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: 27px;
   color: #fff;
}

#search .close:hover{
  color: #FC2121;
  cursor: pointer;
}








body {margin:0;}

.icon-bartop {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bartop a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bartop a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<body>

<div class="icon-bartop">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
</div>




<div class="sidebar">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <div class="icon-bar">
   <a  href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
 </div>
</div>



<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @PerrinPrograms. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are trying to change it by styling the ".active" selector which will change them both like you explained because they both share that class. I recommend giving [MDN - CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) a look to get a better understanding.

That said, a simple solution to your problem would to be to make sure you are using different CSS selectors for different styles

```js
console.log('Loaded')
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4CAF50e;
  border: none;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {margin:10}

.icon-bar {
    width: 90px;
 height: 100%;
    background-color: #555;   /*button color*/
}

.icon-bar a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #4289b5;
}

/* Remove this
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}
*/

/* Add this - Select the side bar active icon */
.icon-bar a.active {
  background-color: green;
}

body{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a{
  
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 3;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FC2121;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;  
}

/* Search Style */ 
#search {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);
           transform: translate(0px, -100%) scale(0, 0);    
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

#search.open {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
       -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
        -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
            transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1); 
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 106;
    display: block;
}

#search input[type="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -51px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   background: transparent;
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   border-left: 0px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    font-size: 40px;
   font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
   padding: 10px;
}
  
#search .close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
   opacity: 1;
   font-size: 27px;
   color: #fff;
}

#search .close:hover{
  color: #FC2121;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {margin:0;}

.icon-bartop {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bartop a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bartop a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
/* Remove this
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}
*/

/* Add this - Select top bar active icon */
.icon-bartop a.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<body>

<div class="icon-bartop">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
</div>




<div class="sidebar">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <div class="icon-bar">
   <a class="active" href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
 </div>
</div>



<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend W3 Schools for anything. It's well-known to have out-of-date or flat out wrong information. Use The Mozilla Developer's Network ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)), for most documentation as it is known to be an authoritative resource.

Comment: I only referenced w3cschools cause it is has a simple list... but I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `class="active"` from this two lines (or from which you want to stop being active):

```
<a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a class="active" href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are `font-awesome` icons, so you can change the color targeting this classes: `fa-home` and `fa-search`, try adding this rules:

```
.fa.fa-home{
      color:#000000; // Change here the color
} 

.fa.fa-search{
      color:#000000; // Change here the color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning both of the elements the `.active` class, which makes the background green. If you just one of them to be green at a time, you have to assign the class to only one of them.

In order to switch the "green" element/button you need to use JavaScript to remove from one and add to the other.

If this isn't what you're looking for please provide me with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Search and Home are in the same css class, so it will pull the same background color...
html:

```
    <div class="icon-bar">
      <a class="search" href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```